# installed Kubeflow - juju bootstrap microk8s error-time out waiting for controller pod

Tags: kubeflow, microk8s, juju

I installed in the official document (https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/quickstart) Kubeflow, to perform juju bootstrap microk8s encountered a bug
[image]

I tried to change the installation of different versions, and encountered the same problem
[image]
[image]